# php, как правильно получить данные используя регулярное выражение

Tags: php

у меня есть данные в файлику

```
(24266, 4, 64, 0, 2267, '59.5000'),
(24267, 4, 69, 0, 2267, '0.3000'),
(24268, 4, 64, 0, 2268, '22.4000'),
(24269, 4, 69, 0, 2268, '0.3000'),
(24270, 4, 64, 0, 2269, '45.5000'),
```

Как сделать так , что когда бежит цыкло, то в  в переменной хранилось что то на подобии

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(24266)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(64)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  int(2267)
  [5]=>
  string(7) "59.5000"
}
```

Comment: и зачем тут регулярное выражение?

Comment: если можно не регулярным, дайте ответ пожалуйста как это реализовать.

Comment: операция разовая или периодическая (можно ли формат файла изменить) ?

Comment: формат файла изменить можно и операция разовая будет

Comment: тогда уберите пробелы,скобки и запятую в конце строки, а на стороне пхп сделайте `$data = file("input.txt"); foreach($data as $line){ $v = explode(',', $line); var_dump($v);}`и получите искомое

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseLine(string $line)
{
   return explode(' ', str_replace(['(',')',','], '', trim($line)));
}


$lines = file('file.txt');

$data = array_map(function($line) {
    return  parseLine($line);
}, $lines);


print_r($data);
```

Далее уже можете смотреть, если элемент в кавычках - удалить их и превратить в строку - если нет то в int